# How to create instance only once at app startup and using them in views

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a requirement to get data form other data source. so I initialize connection instance in my `settings.py`.

and imported in views, utilities where ever required but am using it in many places so I feel to create connection instance only once at app startup and use that instance where ever required.

**Is there any way to create insistence at `manage` main method and make available for application**

or any other workaround ??

thanks in advance:)

Comment: What is the "other data source"? Is it a database?

Comment: Yes. but we cant access through django ORM

Comment: Cause the best way for it would be: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: manage.py isn't used in production, so doing anything there is not a good approach.

Comment: @DanielRoseman any other best practice to solve my problem. I want to initialize connection instance only and and need to use that across application